# How can I differentiate between a multi-word argument and a second argument?

Tags: python, function, discord.py

So, I'm writing a Discord bot in Python, and I made a poll command. However, the issue is that whenever I try to make a multi-word poll (Such as "Who is better?") it takes the first word as the poll name, but everything else becomes options.

To put it simply...

```
#Poll command, command prefix is $
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx,message,q1,q2,q3=None,q4=None,q5=None):
    q1r = '1️⃣'
    q2r = '2️⃣'
    q3r = '3️⃣'
    q4r = '4️⃣'
    q5r = '5️⃣'
    msg = q1r + " " + q1 + "\n " + q2r + " " + q2
    if q3 != None:
        msg = msg + "\n " + q3r + " " + q3
    if q4 != None:
        msg = msg + "\n " + q4r + " " + q4
    if q5 != None:
        msg = msg + "\n " + q5r + " " + q5
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message,description=msg)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(q1r)
    await msg.add_reaction(q2r)
    if q3 != None:
        await msg.add_reaction(q3r)
    if q4 != None:
        await msg.add_reaction(q4r)
    if q5 != None:
        await msg.add_reaction(q5r)
```

In a discord server with the bot, I type $poll Who is better? Spider-Man Iron-Man, and I get a poll with the name "Who", and I get options "is", "better?", "Spider-Man", "Iron-Man".
I know it is an issue with how the command is written, but I do not know how to write it so that the poll name can contain multiple words.

Really, I have no idea what to do for this. any help is appreciated, and I would love to fix this so that I can get to working on other commands for the bot.

Comment: Okay, well, until it's fixed in the code, I've discovered I can surround the poll name in parenthesis to make it multi-word. Annoying, but works.

Comment: "In a discord server with the bot, I type $poll Who is better? Spider-Man Iron-Man, and I get a poll with the name "Who", and I get options "is", "better?", "Spider-Man", "Iron-Man"" In your own words, **how should the program know** that `Who is better?` is the title of the poll, and that `Spider-Man` and `Iron-Man` are the options? Why **shouldn't** it determine that `is` and `better?` are options? What is the **rule that tells you** where the title starts, and the option begins? Moreover: how can we separate the options? Why shouldn't `Spider-Man Iron-Man` be a single option?

Comment: Underlying this, it seems like you are saying that the problem has to do with controlling **how the Discord library decides** to split up the command text, in order to set the values `q1` etc. So - did you try to **read the documentation** for `bot.command`, in order to understand what logic it uses for this purpose, and what customization is possible?

Comment: Well, truly, I would prefer that each parameter is seperated by commas by the user inputting the command, as it makes sense. The issue is figuring out how to tell the program that a comma separates each argument and is not part of the argument itself. Didn't see anything that'd help me with that in the documentation, sadly.

Comment: The [documentation seems clear to me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters). You are expected, in the UI, to use quotes around multi-word parameters, and this is not readily customizable.

Comment: Yeah. To be fair, it does seem that way, and that is mostly why I said that I didn't see anything that would help me. I don't think I ever said that the documentation wasn't clear to me, but more that I could not find anything that would help me make it function how I would prefer it function. When I really think about it, it **may** be possible to split the command by commas and do it that way, but it would probably end up being more complex than it needs to be. Other than that, the only solution I see is to use slash commands instead, but I don't want to do that, so I can't really do much.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel kwargs-style parameter lists & custom converters do allow you to customize that behaviour.

Comment: I would recommend looking into slash commands (using CommandTree, I believe) as a better option – it is officially recommended by Discord, and it will allow you to construct your inputs separately in Discord so you don't have to quote or manually split them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an asterisk (`*`) to make your arguments parse differently, just like regular Python functions. By default, discord.py splits a string on spaces, but wrapping something in `"double quotes"` will parse it as 1 string (even though there's a space in there).

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters

```py
async def command(ctx, argument1, argument2):
    # Invoking "!command first second" will be parsed as
    # argument1: "first"
    # argument2: "second"

# Varargs-style
async def command(ctx, argument1, *argument2):  # Note the asterisk
    # Invoking "!command first second third fourth" will be parsed as
    # argument1: "first"
    # argument2: ("second", "third", "fourth")

# Keyword-args-style
async def command(ctx, argument1, *, argument2):  # Note the position of the asterisk
    # Invoking "!command first second third fourth" will be parsed as
    # argument1: "first"
    # argument2: "second third fourth"
```

You mentioned in the comments that you'd like to split the arguments based on commas instead, and you can use basic Python string splitting for that, combined with the third option above ^. Taking the entire argument as 1 single string and using `.split(",")` should do what you want. Though you might want to call `strip()` on them in case people add spaces before/after their commas.

Alternatively, you can write your own custom [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#basic-converters) to parse the arguments yourself into a custom class & make the string parsing a bit fancier. All up to you.